# Check expression in java

Tags: java, expression

Sorry about my English. Updated the question:

Language C#:

```
using LV.Parsenet.dll;

var result = "IF(TL_HS_NGUNG_LUONGKY1 = 1, 0, TL_HS_K_DC_KY1 * NS_HSL * TL_HS_TL_TTDV)";
Parser m_cParser = new Parser();
ExpressionTree m_oExpressionTree = null;

try
{
    m_oExpressionTree = m_cParser.Parse(result);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.Message();
}
```

Above the code in C#, the method **Parse** check input parameter. And I will know that formula string return true or false. I'm using **lv.parsenet.dll**.
 Where i can find library like that to **check formula in Java**?

Thanks everyone

Comment: unclear question..

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and add more information

Comment: Hey Quan, as mentioned already, your question is somewhat unclear. Please have a look at the [ask] article in the help centre for some tips on how you can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your expression as

```
(TL_HS_NGUNG_LUONGKY1 == 1)? 0: TL_HS_K_DC_KY1 * NS_HSL * TL_HS_TL_TTDV;
```

Since it become javascript expression, you can use it as following

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
    engine.getContext();
    engine.eval("TL_HS_NGUNG_LUONGKY1=10");
    engine.eval("TL_HS_TL_TTDV=10");
    engine.eval("TL_HS_K_DC_KY1=20");
    engine.eval("NS_HSL=20");
    Object result = engine.eval("(TL_HS_NGUNG_LUONGKY1 == 1)? 0: TL_HS_K_DC_KY1 * NS_HSL * TL_HS_TL_TTDV;");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Or use the external library called Shy-Ta

```
public static void main(String[] arg){
    ExpressionsEvaluator evalExpr = new ExpressionsBuilder("IF(TL_HS_NGUNG_LUONGKY1 == 1, 0, TL_HS_K_DC_KY1 * NS_HSL * TL_HS_TL_TTDV)").build();
    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    variables.put("TL_HS_NGUNG_LUONGKY1", 10);
    variables.put("TL_HS_K_DC_KY1", 10);
    variables.put("NS_HSL", 1);
    variables.put("TL_HS_TL_TTDV", 12);
    System.out.println(evalExpr.eval(variables));

}
```